# Refresh config on form show

Tags: c#, forms, app-config

I have a windows form application which uses a series of labels to display the app config settings. From this form i open a further form which is the configuration editor that uses a property grid. Hide parent, Show child, Amend Config, Save, close child, show parent, refresh parent does not reload the configuration.

I hacked something together where I create a new form but i know that is bad practice and leaves an invisible hung process.

My question is, How can i update all of the labels on the parent form following changes saved when in the child form without creating a new instance of the parent form?

A colleague made it sound easy, call the MainForm_onload he said. I spent a few hours with an experienced coder last night trying to get to the bottom of it, but he never works with windows forms so we couldn't figure it out.

Thanks!
~D

Comment: Trigger an event when you save the settings.  When the parent form receives the event, update the labels.  Or however you displayed the settings in the parent form in the first instance, do that again to refresh the labels.  If you assign a new value to Label.Text this will update that label.

Comment: Trierd something like this last night, except the event aimed to reload the whole form. So the labels them selves need to be re-set then i take it? There's about thirty of them, and they are set on the MainForm_onload (nothing else happens in there) and so i hoped to just retrigger that check?

Comment: Just have a method which sets all the labels, then when you receive the event you can just call that method once to update the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be with how you are parsing the data from the app.config to the labels. I guess you are using [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx), so maybe all you have to do is read again the same way you did the first time.

Comment: They are all read on the MainForm_onload, so i either want to be able to re-trigger that or alternatively something like ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

Comment: But we tried RefreshSection last night, it didnt play ball (unless form.Refresh is not sufficient to pick up the changes and i need to refresh the labels individually?)

Comment: When you close the second form, after the edits are saved on the app.config file, read again. Call the same things you call on the main form load, extract it to a separate method (or class) and call from from the other window.

Comment: Thanks, I went with this

Comment: This isn't quite going to plan, I'm using events now... When the event triggers the app config settings appear to be read but the label.text = cfg.setting  isnt refreshing it. I have tried label.refresh() and even setting label.text = "" before setting it to cfg.setting. Its like despite cycling through the app settings it isn't passing new values to the labels.

Comment: Fixed with    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass parameters to the child form. If so pass a delegate `func<T,TResult>()` to your child. When it saves, invoke the function and in your parent implement it to update your variables.

You can then even send the new values as a result so you don't need to look them all up again.

Comment: I think this would need a rewrite to work, i'm using a third party config editor (child form) and its intended to run as a standalone, you just call it from a click event